# When does a functional from a vector's span to $\mathbb{R}$ have a unique norm-preserving extension to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Here's my question:

Consider the space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty).$ For which vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can we say that any linear functional $f: \langle v \rangle \to \mathbb{R}$ has a unique norm-preserving extension to the whole space?

My thought is that this question can be reduced to asking for which vectors we can find a sub-linear function $p$ such that $f$ is dominated by $p$ on $v$'s span. Hahn-Banach then guarantees that $f$ has an extension to the whole space, but that extension doesn't necessarily have to be unique, which I think is where this question gets tricky. At the moment, I'm trying to think about what further conditions we'd need to be guaranteed a unique extension. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is evidently invariant under scalar multiplication so we may suppose that both $\|v\|=1$ and $\|f\|=1$, in
which case $f$ is necessarily given by $f(\lambda v)=\pm\lambda $.  We may further replace $v$ by $-v$, if necessary, so as to be able
to assume that $f(\lambda v)=\lambda $.

Next  notice that a linear functional $g$, defined on the whole ${\bf R}^n$,  has norm less than or equal to one, if and only
if the affine hyperplane
$$
  \{x\in {\bf R}^n:g(x)=1\}
  $$
has empty intersection with the open unit ball $B(0, 1)$.

In order to produce a norm-preserving extension  of our given functional $f$,  we must therefore construct an affine
hyperplane passing thru $v$,  and leaving the whole of $B(0, 1)$ to the same side.

Noticing that $B(0, 1)$ is actually the cube $(-1,1)^n$,
observe that if $v$ is one of the vertices of that cube, say
$v = (\pm 1,\pm 1,\ldots , \pm1)$, then there are many ways to build a hyperplane thru $v$ not intercepting $B(0,1)$.

[image]
The same goes for the case in which $v$ is in any edge of the cube, but of course not if $v$ is an interior point of one
of its faces.  Precisely, this means that $v$ must have one, and no more that one, coordinate with absolute value 1, so
voilà the
condition for the Hahn-Banach extension to be unique!

Comment: Could you please explain why  $\| g \|_\infty \leq 1$ is equivalent to the condition of the hyperplane you defined not intersecting the open unit ball? I'm not sure if I see it yet.

Comment: If the ball does not intercept that hyperplane, then it is contained in the semi-space $\{x:f(x)<1\}$ because the ball is connected and 0 belongs to that semi-space.  Therefore $\sup_{\|x\|<1}|f(x)|\leq 1$.

Comment: Okay, so in other words, if the ball didn't intersect the hyperplane then there's some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|x\|_\infty < 1$ and $g(x) = 1$, and then $\|g\|_\mathrm{op} \geq g(x) / \|x\|_\infty > 1$?

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant answer!

Comment: You are very welcome!